# QTP unable to identify java object

Tags: java, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, qtplugin

QTP version 11 is unable to identify any java object instead it is identifying it just as a window

I tried to spy the java application but QTP is identifying it as a window.

So, is it a QTP issue,missing patch or environment variable issue

Comment: How exactly does this relate to vb.net?

Answer (score 3):

You need to quit UFT, restart it and ensure you have selected the Java Add-in, or this will happen...

Comment: Before you quit UFT, make sure the Add-in manager will display.  On the UFT menu bar, click on Tools > Options...  and then in the Startup options group, make sure to check "Display Add-in Manager on startup".    Then, restart UFT and make sure to check the checkmark for Java addin.

Comment: Another possible reason is that: remember always open UFT FIRST, then launch the application...